# Releasing a pointer that points a static array

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following array declared inside a header file.

```
static const float elementsArray[300] = { ... };
```

I want to do:

```
float *elementsPointer = &elementsArray[0];
```

I'm sure I can do that, but... Do I need to release `elementsPointer` with `delete`?

Do I need to do anything else?

Thank you.

Comment: You're sure you can do that but you can't because it is not const-correct. You are assigning a pointer to a writable data to memory that is declared as const.

Comment: For C++ you should be using `new[]` and `delete[]`, not `malloc` and `free`

Comment: @CashCow: I only need elementsPointer to read elements, I'm not going to modify them. I'm doing this because I'm not sure where elements will be. This code will be inside a switch statement and I need a known var (elementsPointer) to access elements. Depending the case, elementsPointer will point to a static array or to other.

Comment: @VansFennel: The fact that you only need read access to the array elements is precisely why the pointer should be declared `const float *`. Also, statically defined global objects in header files are a bad idea, you'll run into multiple definitions of that object if the header is included in multiple source files. You should be declaring the array in a source file and then adding an extern declaration to the associated header file.

Comment: @Praetorian: So, I need to remove every static arrays from header files and declare them inside source code. Sorry, I'm not very good with English, and I need to repeat what you've said to show you if I've understood.

Comment: @VansFennel: Yep, that would be the right way to do it. Unless the header file in question is only ever going to be included in one source file, in which case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The memory that elementsPointer points to is statically allocated and does not require a call to free.

Comment: I suppose that I don't need to do a malloc either, isn't it?

Comment: @VansFannel: What would you be malloc'ing? The array is allocated statically and exists when your code starts executing.

Comment: @Vans Static arrays don't have `malloc()`, correct. That's why they also don't have `free()`.

Comment: You don't need a malloc here because your data is of fixed size. If it were of variable size determined at runtime then it would require a malloc and a subsequent free. By the way this is tagged at C++ but you are writing C code.

Comment: @CashCow: Sorry, I've forgotten also everything of C++. I will change my question.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to release elementsPointer with free

Exactly the opposite - you must *not* free that particular pointer value since it hasn't been allocated with `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

If that pointer might sometimes be assigned with a value that was dynamically allocated you'll need to arrange (maybe with a flag) to call `free()` only with those memory blocks (if the code using `elementsPointer` is responsible for freeing that memory).

Answer (score 2):

Do not release `elementsPointer`; the `elementsArray` still exists. In fact, you can't `free()` any statically declared array.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is nothing preventing a call to `free()` on a static pointer.  The code will compile just fine. If the call is executed, it results in undefined behavior.  This make be a crash during the free operation (best case), a crash sometime later, or silent, occasional data corruption (worst case).